# Get Multiple Field Values Out Separately In Twig

Tags: theming, entities, 8

I have a content type called 'locations' with a bunch of plain text fields. Each field allows for multiple values.

For example, one of the fields is named 'support' and allows for an unlimited amount of entries. This is because this will be able to accept email address and telephone numbers etc.

I've made a view that takes the latest 2 of this content type, and I'm editing the template used for the single view `views-view-fields--locations.html.twig`.

I can display the values of each field with `{{ fields.field_telephone.content }}`, however I can't seem to get the multiple values out, only the first. Kint's really not being helpful (it won't let me kint all the fields or simply a specific field without crashing).

Comment: '.content' is always displaying what was previously set on the UI (in views in this case). Are you sure you have the right settings in views in this field?

Comment: I've unchecked display all items in a single row, and that's it.

Comment: Well, in your case I would still play arountd with "fields" instead of content. If you go content, you have to check the node content type display page. This has nothing to do with twig, but rather the settings you have. Hard to give you advice tho.

Comment: I don't think there's anything else I can do regarding the field settings. It's just a simple text field, that allows multiple values. I need to be able to get each value out, to loop through them. For some reason, only the first value is coming out.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Im having trouble getting at the individual values for a field with multiple values.